# Using A BMP as heightmap. How to access pixel color to set up heights?

Tags: c++, directx-9

So I'm trying to create some simple terrain using a bmp and I don't know how to access the pixel color to get it's RGB value to use as the height. I understand the concept, just not how to put it into practice. This is the code I have so far. Any help is very much appreciated!

```
CUSTOMVERTEX vecArray[256][256];

m_pSurface = nullptr;
D3DXIMAGE_INFO imageInfo;
ZeroMemory(&imageInfo, sizeof(D3DXIMAGE_INFO));

HRESULT hr = D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile(L"heightmap.bmp", &imageInfo);

_pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(imageInfo.Width, imageInfo.Height, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SCRATCH, &m_pSurface, 0);

hr = D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile(m_pSurface, 0, 0, L"heightmap.bmp", 0, D3DX_FILTER_NONE, 0, &imageInfo);

D3DLOCKED_RECT lockRect;
ZeroMemory(&lockRect, sizeof(D3DLOCKED_RECT));

m_pSurface->LockRect(&lockRect, 0, D3DLOCK_READONLY);

int iNumPixels = imageInfo.Width * imageInfo.Height;
int iPixelsWidth = imageInfo.Width;
int iPixelsHeight = imageInfo.Height;

for (int i = 0; i < iPixelsWidth; ++i)          // HORIZONTAL ROWS
{
    for (int j = 0; j < iPixelsHeight; ++j)     // VERTICAL ROWS
    {
        vecArray[i][j].x = (float)i;
        vecArray[i][j].y = (float)j;

        vecArray[i][j].z = ???? // Get Height from bmp

        vecArray[i][j].color =  D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255);
    }
}

m_pSurface->UnlockRect();
```

The struct is define as:

```
struct CUSTOMVERTEX
{
    FLOAT x, y, z;  // The untransformed, 3D position for the vertex
    DWORD color;
};
```

Comment: All the old 'demos' I saw from 10+ years ago used 8 bit bitmaps with a pallette. The pallete was discarded, leaving you with an array of 8bit numbers, giving you 256 different height levels. Here's a page that deals with 24bit bmps and directX. http://rastertek.com/tertut02.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the pixels mapped into a buffer, interpolate the color value as an integer (range 0 to 255) to your height range. If you are using a 3-channel image (rgb) you will need to first average the channels to one value (ie. (r + g + b) / 3). That will give you a single value for the pixel.

See "linear interpolation" to convert from pixel range to height range.  If you're asking how to access the pixel values themselves, that depends on the method used to load the bitmap.

Comment: I'm trying to create terrain from a heightmap. I've loaded the bmp onto a surface as you can see in the code. I'm asking how do I access the data specifically on a certain pixel to get its color so I can use that as height. So then after that I can create buffers.

Comment: If you already have it loaded to a surface, use LockRect() to get a pointer to the pixel buffer. I'm not sure how DirectX works, but you may want to avoid loading to surface for a heightmap, since a surface is designated as a texture. There are other ways of loading a DIB's pixel data outside of DirectX. DIB is the windows bmp format. It's a relatively simple format.

Comment: I have some DIB loading code that can load DIB bmp's into a buffer. If you'd like a copy of said code send me an email ido.somecoding@gmail.com